# ...And then there was silence... (to our esteemed CMs)

Tags: support, moderator

TildalWave has quit his moderator's position. Our esteemed CMs were quick to clean up the details of his resignation and chat transcripts, but are obviously playing the Cunctator when it comes to thanking him in public for the years he spent on building the community and dealing with moonwits and nutcases, while at the same time writing extremely well-researched answers.

Well, I'll leave it to their conscience. TildalWave has humbly moderated this site to the limits of human abilities. I salute him. **Thank you, TW!**

Comment: I do believe we removed some chat items from [The DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz). TildalWave's formal resignation was to me in email several months ago. For better or worse, I didn't act on that resignation until prompted again in a private chat room. I also appreciate TildalWave's excellent work as a moderator and as an extremely knowledgeable user. As a rule, we don't announce moderator resignations ourselves because some people prefer to step down quietly. This post would be more honoring of TildalWave if it did not include the mentions of our actions and inactions.

Comment: @JonEricson - all the dishonor is mine :) thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 13):

Let me just state that TildalWave was an excellent moderator, one of if not the best that I've had the privilege to work along side on any site on Stack Exchange. I hope he is able to continue to help this community grow without the weight of a moderator. Thanks for all of your hard work!

Answer (score 0):

I feel compelled to go a bit out on a limb and ask about something here instead of posting a new question, because of the context. Being a moderator has big elements of both customer service rep and cop, two of the most frustrating, thankless, and often abuse-laden jobs in the world. To handle such a grind, people in such fields need a place to growl and blow steam about it with complete freedom, no judgement, with others who know the background and can relate. My understanding is that site moderators always have their own site chat room where they can do just that, as well as consult with each other and such.

My understanding is also that the SX moderator chat room was completely inactive for a long time. Pearson and TildalWave opened it again a few months ago, but I don't know that it was used very much, considering that fact. To have value as a pressure release valve, a mod would need to be able to go there at any time and rag on for a while with other mods until they felt a bit better. I know nothing about T's specific reasons for quitting, but I do know he struggled with a back-log of irritation due to the arguments and lack of respect that come with mod duty, and his baffling lack of personal perfection. I had a persistent impression he didn't have adequate access to a place where he could just be angry without it causing repercussions. From a couple of fights I've had with him over my time here, I can say if he can do that, he calms down easily and has a notably generous spirit afterwards.

So I guess my point is, if our mods are going to be able to maintain the kind of close, careful watch TildalWave contributed to so much, I think they need that space.

Comment: There is such a place that is SE wide, known as the Teacher's Lounge. A single site's chatroom for moderators, while not always heavily used, is primarily for more urgent problems.