# Why the change in moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderator

I like to think that Stack Exchange as a whole is fairly transparent in their processes, and that because of this the communities are trusting of decisions that are made.  One thing that happened last week on Space.SE last week though was the editing of [this post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) where one mod has been replaced with another.

I realise that it may be different on a beta site with unelected mods, but on other sites such a change would result in an announcment much like [this recent one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318714/announcing-our-new-stack-overflow-moderators) on Stack Overflow.  Instead, the change in mods here on Space was done in an edit announcing the pro tem mods rather than the usual thanking of (now-ex) mod for their work and welcoming a new one to take their place.

Can I ask on behalf of the community for the sake of transparency why the change was made in this way, and also why a change at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, this is the common method for pro-tem moderator announcements. The same thing was done in other sites, see as below:

- https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/moderator-pro-tem-announcement
- https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/moderator-pro-tem-announcement

As to why the change was made, it was stated in another post that TildalWave stepped down as moderator, and as 3 moderators is always the minimum desired, we had a new moderator step in, being Kim Holder. I can say that myself and the entire SE Community Team is quite grateful for Tildal's contributions to this site. The reasons why moderators drop out is numerous, and usually isn't discussed in beta sites. But there was a [previous question on such](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/725/25).

Comment: Right, thanks - figured it might be different as they're unelected.  Just seemed odd to have nothing other than an edit on a post announcing it (I don't recall seeing a post from TildalWave, could have missed it though) - appreciate the reply!

Comment: Tildal himself never posted to my knowledge, although he has talked about it in chat.

Comment: Right - also just looked at your final link properly - I see it's just that there's been a gap between him stepping down and the edit on the post.